# How can I fix a "failed to connect to LAN" error in Rome Total War: Gold?

Tags: macos, rome-total-war, mac-app-store

I recently purchased *Rome Total War: Gold* via the Mac App Store on OS X Lion. I have had a lot of fun playing the single player campaign.

However, when I try to access multiplayer to battle against my friends by going to Multiplayer → LAN Battles, I get to enter my player name, but after that the game freezes for a short while and an error appears:

> Failed to connect to LAN

The error occurs in the normal version as well as in Barbarian Invasion. My friend (on a Windows machine) does get into the lobby after entering his player name.

I disabled all and any firewalls and antivirus but I can't seem to solve the problem.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Even feral-interactive is having trouble discovering the issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution finally ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, if I remember correctly it had something to do with combining windows/macos versions.

Comment: Can you traceroute the connection to the LAN host? Perhaps settings on your router are preventing (packet filtering, forwarding, etc) transit?